# Find a Package for a given ProductId

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-package-manager

I have the [ProductId](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.preview.installcontrol.appinstallitem.productid?view=winrt-22621) for an app:

> https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/msn-weather/9WZDNCRFJ3Q2

Where the ProductId is 9WZDNCRFJ3Q2. This is used by [AppInstallManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.preview.installcontrol.appinstallmanager.startappinstallasync?view=winrt-22621) to programmatically install from Store.

I would like to know if an app is already installed, based on its ProductId alone. Is it possible to find a package on a device given only the ProductId?

Comment: Does my suggestion work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to find a package on a device given only the ProductId?

No, you can't find the app via the ProduceID. There is no API could do that.

If you could get the `packageFullName` of the target app, there is another option for you to find if an app is installed on the device. The [PackageManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager?view=winrt-22621) contains 4 different methods which could find specific packages installed on the device.

- [FindPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackage?view=winrt-22621)
- [FindPackageForUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackageforuser?view=winrt-22621)
- [FindPackages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackages?view=winrt-22621)
- [FindPackagesForUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackagesforuser?view=winrt-22621)

These methods require the `packageFullName` as the parameter. And you need to call these APIs in a desktop application because these methods require administrative privileges.

Comment: It's not super ideal as I've only depended on the ProductId until now and requiring an additional parameter is a non-trivial change...

Can the PackageFullName be retrieved via a Store API call?

Comment: @TomSelleck Are you trying to get the PackageFullName for other apps that are not developed by you? If it is, the answer is no.